# Uncarved Pumpkin - is it still okay to cook with?

Tags: pumpkin

Is there a way to tell if the insides of my pumpkins are still okay to cook with?  Assuming the innards smell okay, is it fine to eat?  Is it possible for the pumpkin to smell fine but not actually be fine?

Comment: How does it sound?

Comment: Any soft spots or traces of mold? How does the stem look like and how did you store it?

Comment: Cut it open? ...sniffy sniff.

Comment: Not a duplicate -- the other one was about selection of pumpkins -- this one's about storage issues for one that you already have (which might not be all that great to cook with).

Comment: If anything, it's more closely related to http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20084/67